# python selenium find_element_by_link_text, element exists but not found

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, linktext, partiallinktext

I'm trying to click this link using selenium in python:

```
<header class="row package-collapse">
    <h5 ng-bind="ctrl.getPackageHeader(package)" class="ng-binding">Package "1" - not yet downloaded</h5>
    <!-- ngIf: package.DownloadedAt -->
</header>
```

After trying many different alternatives, I have finally managed to accomplish this by iterating through links until I find the right text, like this:

```
list = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("h5")
for item in list:
    text = item.text
    if text == 'Package "1" - not yet downloaded':
        item.click()
```

OK, so, it works. But why on earth should I get an "unable to locate element" error if I just try the obvious solution:

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text('Package "1" - not yet downloaded')
```

It's right there and I'm looking at it, so I just don't get what I'm doing wrong. I've also tried using partial link text to search for it without the "1", using single or double quotes, but I still get "unable to locate element." There are no frames, no new windows opening or anything.

And yes, I'm posting this because I'm a novice and have no clue what I'm doing, so no need to belabor that particular point, thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `by_link_text` works only on `<a>` tags. For other tags you can use `xpath`

Exact match

```
find_element_by_xpath("//h5[.='Package \"1\" - not yet downloaded']")
```

And for partial text

```
find_element_by_xpath("//h5[contains(., '\"1\" - not yet downloaded')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

It explained in the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text) that `find_element_by_link_text` only work with href text inside anchor tag, you pointing to an h5 tag and "Package "1" - not yet downloaded" is not in anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle your h5 element using text then please use below xpath

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Package \"1\" - not yet downloaded')]")
```

`find_element_by_link_text` will only work with link. i.e href

Answer (score 0):

Try find_element_by_partial_link_text. 'Partial' made the difference to pull info from a public site.